# WEKA - JDBC Connection Exception

Tags: java, jdbc, data-mining, weka

I'm facing JDBC connection problem while trying to connect MySQL DB using WEKA.

Here's my **DatabaseUtils.properties** file:

```
jdbcDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbcURL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
```

**And I added jdbc-mysql jar into the path:**

```
/opt/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/talha/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin:/home/talha/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.jar:/opt/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:/home/talha/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_05/bin:/home/talha/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin
```

**Java Class [A simple test class]**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        InstanceQuery query = new InstanceQuery();
        query.setUsername("username");
        query.setPassword("password");
        String sql = "select * from user";
        query.setQuery(sql);
        // if your data is sparse, then you can say so too
        // query.setSparseData(true);
        Instances data = query.retrieveInstances();

    }

}
```

**Full stacktrace:**

```
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): RmiJdbc.RJDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.mckoi.JDBCDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:33305', transport: 'socket'
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:idb=experiments.prp
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
    at weka.experiment.DatabaseUtils.connectToDatabase(DatabaseUtils.java:521)
    at weka.experiment.InstanceQuery.retrieveInstances(InstanceQuery.java:286)
    at weka.experiment.InstanceQuery.retrieveInstances(InstanceQuery.java:271)
    at com.tk.miner.Test.main(Test.java:22)
```

Comment: Did you added jdbc-mysql jar added in your eclipse class path?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ Idea and added jdbc-mysql dependency entry into the my pom.xml file. By the way DatabaseUtils.props is located under src/main/resources.

Comment: Why is it trying to load `jdbc:idb=experiments.prp`? Oh, and your `PATH` is a **mess**.

Comment: I've no idea why it tries to load `jdbc:idb=experiments.prp`. Actually yeah the path looks like mess but there's nothing wrong I think.. Any other ideas to solve this error would be appreciated a lot..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to JavaDocs [InstanceQuery](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/experiment/InstanceQuery.html) defaults to "jdbc.idbDriver" and "jdbc:idb=experiments.prp".

You can override them with `DatabaseUtils.properties` file. Try putting `DatabaseUtils.props` in **user.home** (/home/talha/ ?) or the **current directory** (in Eclipse current directory is project folder that contains `src` folder - no idea where it is on IntelliJ Idea).

Comment: thanks a lot hkn, you saved my day! actually I read from somewhere(I don't remember) to put this file in WEKA_HOME/props which means user.home/wekafiles/props. Thanks again correcting this wrong information.

Comment: According to http://weka.wikispaces.com/Properties+File , version of Weka determines the paths: (< Weka 3.7.2) the user's home directory; (>= Weka 3.7.2) $WEKA_HOME/props